# Adding image on Fabric.js canvas at mouse coords results in offset image position

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have a rather trivial example where I'm attempting to insert an image on a Fabric.js canvas with the image centered at the mouse coordinates. The center of the cursor should be the exact center of the image.

I calculate the center of the image by halving its width and height and apply them as offsets to the `left` and `top` coordinates of the `canvas.Image` I'm inserting. Simple enough:

```
// Coordinates from the mouse click event. 
// `x` and `y` are aliases for `clientX`, `clientY`, respectively
const x = event.e.x,
      y = event.e.y

image.set({
    left: x - (image.width / 2),
    top: y - (image.height / 2)
})

canvas.add(image);
```

When the image is added, it's not quite center. In fact, there's a difference of 8 pixels on both `x` and `y` axes that I cannot account for.

This is the result:

[image: The center of the image should be under the cursor.]

The center of the image should be under the cursor.

If I manually set the offset to 28, the image is properly centered. But since I cannot account for the 8 extra pixels, this hack is unacceptable.

[image: Centered]

Working sample:

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', { width: 400, height: 150 });

// Add an image centered x & y at the exact point the user clicks.
canvas.on('mouse:up', (opt) => {
  canvas.clear();

  const x = opt.e.x,
        y = opt.e.y;

  fabric.Image.fromURL('https://i.imgur.com/htyNxF6.png', (image) => {

    /* Calculate the offset based on the image dimensions:
        This does not work as expected. A 40x40 image has a x/y offsets of 20.
        If we set the offset to 28, the image is centered at the cursor. Why 28?
        Check the "Apply ..." checkbox to see this in action.
    */
    const offsetX = chkOffset.checked ? 28 : (image.width / 2),
          offsetY = chkOffset.checked ? 28 : (image.height / 2);

    const left = x - offsetX,
           top = y - offsetY;

    image.set({
      left: left,
      top: top,
      stroke: 0,
      padding: 0,
      centeredScaling: true,
      hasControls: false,
      strokeWidth: 0,
      hasBorders: 0
    });

    canvas.add(image);

    writeDebug(`Mouse at: x=${x}, y=${y}; 
                Image placed at: x=${left}, y=${top}
                Difference of ${Math.abs(left-x)}, ${Math.abs(top-y)}`);

  });

  // Show coordinates on mouse move
  canvas.on('mouse:move', (opt) => {
    const x = opt.e.x,
          y = opt.e.y;
    writeDebug(`Mouse coordinates: x=${x}, y=${y}`);
  });



});

function writeDebug(message) {
  document.getElementById('debug').innerText = message;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Consolas;
}

#c {
  border: 1px solid #ececec;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #c0c0c0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.1.0/fabric.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="c"></canvas>

<label for="chkOffset">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chkOffset" />
  Apply 28px offset
</label>

<div id="debug">Click in the canvas to add the image</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When I was adding sample code to my question, I stumbled upon the answer. I set the padding of every element to 10 using CSS (`* { padding: 10px }`) to make everything look better and upon doing so discovered that the offset gap had increased.

Getting mouse coordinates using `MouseEvent.e.x` and `MouseEvent.x.y` are the culprit. I compared their values with `MouseEvent.e.offsetX` and `MouseEvent.e.offsetY` and found that the `x` and `y` values did not account for padding and margins.

Using `offsetX` and `offsetY` seemed to do the trick.

It seems if you want to get relevant mouse coordinates in Fabric.js, using `offsetX` and `offsetY` is the best bet as it accounts for offsets caused by CSS.

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', { width: 400, height: 150 });

// Add an image centered x & y at the exact point the user clicks.
canvas.on('mouse:up', (opt) => {
  canvas.clear();

  // Use .offset instead:
  const x = opt.e.offsetX,
        y = opt.e.offsetY;

  fabric.Image.fromURL('https://i.imgur.com/htyNxF6.png', (image) => {

    const offsetX = (image.width / 2),
          offsetY = (image.height / 2);

    const left = x - offsetX,
           top = y - offsetY;

    image.set({
      left: left,
      top: top,
      stroke: 0,
      padding: 0,
      centeredScaling: true,
      hasControls: false,
      strokeWidth: 0,
      hasBorders: 0
    });

    canvas.add(image);

    writeDebug(`Mouse at: x=${x}, y=${y}; 
                Image placed at: x=${left}, y=${top}
                Difference of ${Math.abs(left-x)}, ${Math.abs(top-y)}`);

  });

  // Show coordinates on mouse move
  canvas.on('mouse:move', (opt) => {
    const x = opt.e.offsetX,
          y = opt.e.offsetY;
    writeDebug(`Mouse coordinates: x=${x}, y=${y}`);
  });



});

function writeDebug(message) {
  document.getElementById('debug').innerText = message;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Consolas;
}

#c {
  border: 1px solid #ececec;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #c0c0c0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.1.0/fabric.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="c"></canvas>

<div id="debug">Click in the canvas to add the image</div>
```

Comment: to get mouse position use [canvas.getPointer()](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#getPointer)

Comment: Wow, thanks @Durga! I looked for something like that in the Fabric API for a while and didn't find anything.